# Check HTTP Status Code in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-codes

Is there an easy way to check the status code of another website (e.g. http://google.com) in Ruby on Rails?

Ideally, the list of URLs to check would be pulled from a DB and processed via CRON (or equivalent).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com',80)
response = http.request_get('/')
p response.status
```

Slightly more efficient (traffic wise) might be:

```
response = http.request_head('/')
p response.status
```

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M001403

Comment: Thanks! Where is the best place to put this to automate it (e.g. via CRON)? Does it belong in a Ruby file of its own?

Comment: If it is using the database, and activerecord makes sense, you could put it in a rails project and the stub that loads everything in a file in /script. Have the stub use require to load your worker and start it running. The files I usually put into app/workers/someworker. I launch this type of thing with a call from cron setup via crontab -e.

Comment: It is not `response.status` but `response.code`, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request env by calling :

```
def index
  @req = (request.env).inspect 
end

# index.html.erb
<%= @req %>
```

Comment: The question is about checking the response code of an external website not about getting the env for a local request