# Ping a Server using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to ping a server using Rails. I found this

[Check HTTP Status Code in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476813/check-http-status-code-in-rails)

but I get this error while running this code,

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com',80)
response = http.request_get('/')
p response.status
```

Error:

```
`<main>': undefined method `status' for #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true> (NoMethodError)
```

Why? And why does google returns me a 302 code?? Shouldn't it be 200?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`response.code`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html) if you are using ruby 1.9.